# Not showing the right frequency in ssqueezepy CWT plot

Tags: wavelet, cwt, ssqueezepy

I am following the ssqueezepy simple [example](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/master/examples/se_ans0.py).

The plot should show f=12 but it shows around 33.

[image]

1. Is this a bug or have I scaled the y-axis wrong?
2. Also the plot is not a straight plot as it waves at the right end, close
   to 500.

```
import numpy as np
from ssqueezepy.visuals import imshow
from ssqueezepy import cwt

def _t(min, max, N):
    return np.linspace(min, max, N, False)

def cos_f(freqs, N=128, phi=0):
    return np.concatenate([np.cos(2 * np.pi * f * (_t(i, i + 1, N) + phi))
                           for i, f in enumerate(freqs)])

wavelet = ('morlet', {'mu': 5})
f, N = 12, 512

x = cos_f([f], N=N)
Wx, scales, *_ = cwt(x, wavelet,fs=N)

imshow(Wx, abs=1, yticks=scales, title="f=%d, N=%d" % (f, N), show=1,
       cmap='jet')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note `yticks=scales`. You need frequencies. Regarding the boundary effect, back then I didn't bother to make a perfect sine CWT: long story short, the *padded* signal must be a perfect sine, for `'reflect'` achieved via `endpoint=True`. [Implemented](https://pastebin.com/CwM3EavJ):

[image]

If the link doesn't work, here are the only changes:

```
from ssqueezepy.experimental import scale_to_freq
    return np.linspace(min, max, N, True)
freqs = scale_to_freq(scales, wavelet, N, fs=N)
imshow(Wx, abs=1, yticks=freqs, title="f=%d, N=%d" % (f, N), show=1,
```

Comment: Can't access the link of your implementation. It seems that one should convert the scales to frequency and I use the scale2frequency code of ssquezepy in the latest version. It works for me.

Comment: @EddyPiedad Strange... added.

Comment: Now I can access. Earlier, t´was Error 500. Perfect, I use the same library ´scale_to_frequency´.

Comment: @EddyPiedad Great. If this answers your question, please [mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qslt4.png) it.

Comment: done marking it